# Style tag inside html template (in Aurelia view)?

Tags: css, templates, view, styles, aurelia

Can I put a `<style>` tag inside a template for an Aurelia view?  I'm having a specific issue where if I have a `<style>` tag in the template, my aurelia-dialog is not aligned correctly (it's floated to the top of the screen instead of centered in the middle).  As soon as I remove the `<style>` tag, everything is correctly placed.  What is the proper way to write `.css` classes for a view / template?

Example: For my dialog component (similar to a bootstrap modal), I have a dialog.html and a dialog.js
Inside dialog.html, the code looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <style media="screen">
    .selectedBorder {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }  
  </style>
  <ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-header>
      Header
    </ai-dialog-header>
    <ai-dialog-body>
      Sample body information
    </ai-dialog-body>
    <ai-dialog-footer>
      Footer info
    </ai-dialog-footer>
  </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

Edit:  I figured it out.  You can have `<style>` tags inside templates.  My problem was that i had one template (main screen area) calling another template (popup dialog).  I just had to move the `<style>` from the dialog.html into the main view's html and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the popular consensus, but what I have been doing it making all of my customer elements containerless, eliminating the markup bloat and then namespacing the template content with an id attribute.  For Example:

someView.html:

```
<body>
    <avatar-pic containerless></avatar-pic>
</body>
```

avatar-pic.html

```
<template>
    <section class="avatar-pic">
        ....
    </section>
</template>
```

avatar-pic.css

```
.avatar-pic {
    ...styles here
}
```